# JQuery failed to change background-image URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following style for DIV:

```
#dropzone
    {
        height: 530px;
        width: 530px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius: 10px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        border: 2px dashed #0687FF;
        display: block;
        background-image: url(/Images/RE/02.png);
    }
```

I'm implementing drag and drop function onto the web. And upon dropping the image, I get a whole chunk of strings like below:

[image]

I'm trying to change the background image of my `dropzone` using

```
alert(evt.target.result);
//$('#dropzone').css('background-image', url(evt.target.result));
//$('#dropzone').css('background-image', evt.target.result);
```

Both of the commented way are not working. Please advice

Comment: have you tried putting the values in quotes $('#dropzone').css('background-image', 'url("' + evt.target.result + '")');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try using camelCase notation for the property and interpolate your variable, like so

```
$('#dropzone').css('backgroundImage', 'url(' + evt.target.result + ')');
```

Comment: I've tried with `background-image` as well and it works fine. I'm wondering where to get all the possible tags for best practice purposes?

Comment: What do you mean with "tags for best practice purposes"? It sounds like a too broad question

Comment: I mean it seems like whether we use `background-image` or `backgroundImage` are fine for JQuery? JQuery is not sensitive at all?

Comment: If you look at [jQuery 1.10 source code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js), row 7048 there's a call to a `camelCase()` method. Basically you would skip a `-` replacement. But both version will work in this case

Comment: if you are changing a single property, just use normal CSS names, but if you are updating a few CSS properties in one CSS method, you need to camelCase it, for example: {backgroundImage: 'url(../../etc.jpg)', fontSize: '12px', fontWeight: 900}

Answer (score 0):

You should put a jpg image and see it will appear but there is a problem with png files try this